# django blog zinnia Template Customizing

Tags: django, templates, blogs, zinnia

I was wondering what is the best way for customizing zinnia because by default when installing via pip it installs in site packages do I need to open the site package directory and edit it from there? Just want to know. Plus do I need to do some extreme tweaking to zinnia in other for it to work since all I want is a simple post that, displays entries as a list and detail or I just leave it as it is after installation.

Comment: Hi. Did you create the static dir and collected the statics? This copies the templates into another directory.

Comment: Yes. I have done that. thanks am able to customize it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the comments, you need to create the static dir and collect the templates.

The best place to look and get an explanation is the Django documentation. Here is the link to the deployment section. Please make sure you read the other sections as well: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#deployment